# Is it possible to make another ipywidgets widget appear based on dropdown selection?

Tags: python, jupyter, ipywidgets

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to have different dropdowns/other widgets appear based on the selection in one dropdown. It seems that with 'interact' there are ways to make the values in a second dropdown change based on the values in the first, but I haven't had any luck finding a way to completely change the widgets being displayed based on the first selection. Below is the code that exports my dashboard with ipywidgets - have changed some names in there to make it a bit easier to read without the entire script.

```
top = widgets.Accordion([
    AppLayout(header=header,
              center=VBox([Label('First Selection'),
                           select_1]),

          left_sidebar=VBox([Label('Second Selection'),
                             dropdown_2,

                             Label('Third Selection'),
                             dropdown_3,

                             Label('Fourth Selection'),
                             dropdown_4,

                             Label('Fifth Selection'),
                             dropdown_5,

                             group_checkbox]),

          right_sidebar=VBox([Label('Sixth Selection'),
                              select_6t,
                              Label('Seventh Selection'),
                              select_7]),
          footer=VBox([HBox([text_box,button_export]),HBox([dropdown_eight,nine_slider,ten_text,stage_export,run_export])]),
          pane_widths=['350px', 1, 1],
          pane_heights=['80px', 4, 1],
          height='auto',
          grid_gap="20px")])

pd.options.display.max_columns = None
pd.options.display.max_rows = None

bottom = tab
app = widgets.VBox([top,bottom])

app
```

Basically the list populating the HBox in footer contains other widgets which may or may not have relevance based on the selection in dropdown_eight. Rather than have several rows of widgets, I'd like to be able to have a function that determines which additional widgets are needed based on the selection in dropdown_eight. Initially, I was trying to define a function that would return the appropriate list of widgets but could not get it to update in the dashboard.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find when you have two interlinked widgets, it's easier for me to bind the two together into a class. It's also easier to write a method to access the values you need.

Below is a similar example where you can alter the number of boolean widgets, and then get the chosen values by calling `wm.checks`. Hopefully you can see how it works and adapt to your situation?

```py
import ipywidgets as ipyw
import string

class WidgetMaker(ipyw.VBox):

    def __init__(self):
        self.widget_count = ipyw.IntText(description='Number:')
        self.bool_widget_holder = ipyw.HBox()
        children = [
            self.widget_count,
            self.bool_widget_holder,
        ]
        self.widget_count.observe(self._add_bool_widgets, names=['value'])
        super().__init__(children=children)

    def _add_bool_widgets(self, widg):
        num_bools = widg['new']
        new_widgets = []
        for _, label in zip(range(num_bools), string.ascii_lowercase):
            new_widget = ipyw.Checkbox(description=label)
            new_widgets.append(new_widget)
        self.bool_widget_holder.children = tuple(new_widgets)

    @property
    def checks(self):
        return {
            w.description: w.value
            for w in self.bool_widget_holder.children
        }
```

[image]